# How can I extract Indian languages text such as Marathi from a PDF using Tessaract ocr in Android Studio using Java

Tags: java

I have performed all the steps in code with keeping all the trained data files in asserts directory and the PDF to image as a step in the code but my app crashes for it

This is the code

```java
public class PDFUtils {

    private static final String TAG = "pdf ocr";
    private static final String TESS_DATA = "/tessdata";
    private static final String LANG = "mar+hin";

    public static String extractText(Context context, Uri pdfUri) {
        // Initialize Tesseract OCR
        String dataPath = context.getFilesDir() + TESS_DATA;
        prepareTesseract(context, dataPath);
        TessBaseAPI tessBaseAPI = new TessBaseAPI();
        tessBaseAPI.init(dataPath, LANG);

        // Load and process PDF pages
        String extractedText = "";
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(pdfUri, "r");
            if (fileDescriptor != null) {
                PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
                int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();

                for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pageCount; pageIndex++) {
                    PdfRenderer.Page page = pdfRenderer.openPage(pageIndex);

                    // Render the PDF page as a bitmap image
                    Bitmap pageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(page.getWidth(), page.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    page.render(pageBitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

                    // Process the bitmap image using Tesseract
                    tessBaseAPI.setImage(pageBitmap);
                    extractedText += tessBaseAPI.getUTF8Text();

                    // Close the current page
                    page.close();
                }

                // Close the PDF renderer
                pdfRenderer.close();
                fileDescriptor.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading PDF and extracting text: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Clean up
        tessBaseAPI.end();

        return extractedText;
    }

    private static void prepareTesseract(Context context, String dataPath) {
        try {
            String fileList[] = context.getAssets().list("");
            for (String fileName : fileList) {
                String pathToDataFile = dataPath + TESS_DATA + "/" + fileName;
                if (!(new File(pathToDataFile)).exists()) {
                    InputStream in = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pathToDataFile);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }

                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error preparing Tesseract OCR data: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And how I call it:-

```java
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    public void yourPublicFunction() {
        Uri pdfUri = ...; // Seting the PDF file URI here
        String extractedText = PDFUtils.extractText(this, pdfUri);
        Log.d(TAG, "Extracted Text: " + extractedText);

        
    }
}
```

So I am unable to find the bug in it. I have also tried to do it using itext7 library but in that code I am only able to extract the English text from the pdf. But not the Indian languages.

But by using the Tessaract I am unable to extract anything and the app crashes.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? is that code enough to be considered a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Tesseract support [indian languages](https://indic-ocr.github.io/tessdata/). Could you give details about the libraries that are being used? based on the lines showed, looks like this is for an android app. Please edit your post trying to add debugging details. Also you can check the article [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is the dependency used:- dependencies {
    implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:1.0.2'
}
The error is that the part is not able to extract the text.

Comment: instead of posting your answer to my questions here in comments, edit your post (you can find the button under your question) and add all the debugging details. Show the full message, not just a description. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is hard to help you